# Is it possible in Javascript to get the name of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I know this is completely useless, but I'm nonetheless curious. Is it possible to do something like the below?

```
function getVariableName ( v )
{
    // .... do something ..... 
    // return the string "v" 
}
var x = 69;
var y = "somestring";
console.log(getVariableName(x)); // prints "x" to the console
console.log(getVariableName(y)); // prints "y" to the console
```

Comment: nope, but you can use the `arguments` string

Comment: Why would you need the name?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The mention of `x` in the calling environment results in the *value* of `x` being passed, and a value is just a value; it has no intrinsic relationship to the variable.

Comment: Why do you need the variable name to be printed?

Comment: I couldn't help but wonder, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Can't you just wrap them in quotes?

Comment: This is could only be achieved through static analysis.

Comment: I see the question has been closed, however here's an additional solution `console.log(Object.keys({x:null})[0]);` where you put the variable name where `x` is.

Answer (score -2):

```
function getArgNames(fn) {
    var matches = fn.toString().match(/\(([a-z_, ]+)\)/i);
    if (matches.length > 1) {
        return matches[1].replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',');
    }
    return [];
}
```

That will return an array of the names of all arguments passed in to the function.

Comment: This returns the *formal* parameter names - the names from the function definition. The OP wants the names of variables referenced in calls to the function - the *actual* parameters.

Comment: Ah, right.  It satisfied the "V" example, but not the X and Y conditions. :-/